# SImple Progress Bar for ControlsFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm having some problems with the ControlsFX progress bar dialog, could someone post a simple example of using one? I'm having a hard time figuring out how to update the progress bar and what type of Worker I should use.

My Attempt:

```
Dialogs dialogs = Dialogs.create();
            dialogs.nativeTitleBar().title("Updating Population List").masthead("Updating the population table")
                    .message("The population table is being updated, please be patient.")
                    .owner(this.addNewPerson.getScene().getWindow()).showWorkerProgress(????);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ControlsFX progress bar dialog is expecting a Worker.  The idea is that a worker updates the bar as progress is made on the work.  Remember, though, you can't change live scene graph objects unless your on the JavaFX thread, and you don't want to do long tasks (say those needing a progress bar) on the JavaFX thread.  Don't forget to use Platform.runLater() to actually modify the scene graph.

You can find a pretty good example of what you're trying to do here.

http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-dialogs/

```
    Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
         @Override
             protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                 return new Task<Void>() {
                     @Override
                     protected Void call()throws InterruptedException {
                         updateMessage("Initializing Task");
                                      updateProgress(0, 10);
                                      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                                          Thread.sleep(300);
                                          //DO BACKGROUND WORK HERE

                                          Platform.runLater(new Runnable {
                                              @Override
                                              public void run() {
                                                   //DO LIVE SCENE GRAPH WORK HERE
                                              }
                                          });

                                          updateProgress(i + 1, 10);
                                          updateMessage("Progress Msg");
                                       }
                         updateMessage("Finished");
                         return null;
                     }
               };
             }
         };

         //Once you have your worker, you can create the status dialog
         Dialogs.create()
                 .owner(stage)
                 .title("Progress Dialog")
                 .masthead("Doing The Thing")
                 .showWorkerProgress(service);

         service.start();
```